# sqlalchemy validator for two fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The SQLAlchemy docs explain how to use a @validates decorator to add validation to a model.

```
 from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class EmailAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)

    @validates('email')
    def validate_email(self, key, address):
        assert '@' in address
        return address
```

I've got a model with two dates, and I'd like to create a validator ensuring one date is always greater than the second. Is it possible to create a model level validator? If so what is the syntax?

Comment: Why can't you just validate one and making sure it meets the requirements in the other? E.g. `assert self.repeat_email == address` or similar?

Comment: That could probably work, however I'd need trap any issues during the initialization.  I would really prefer to define a few validators per field, and a row validator to determine if the fields create a valid state. It just feels more explicit and maintinable to have the row validation in one place and not scattered throughout different field validators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example for the validators.

You can use the CheckConstraint in the declaration of your model. Or you can use the @validates decorator. But this one will be called by SQLAlchemy for each name in the first arguments.

```
@validates('started_at', 'stopped_at')
def do_validation(self, key, field):
    return field
```

Please, check this code: https://gist.github.com/matrixise/6417293

Comment: The order in which `started_at` and `stopped_at` is called is random.

Comment: Not random but in order of value passed.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't discuss the order in which `do_validation` will be called for each of the two fields, nor does it show how you'd actually achieve the asker's objective from the question (of checking whether one column's value is smaller than another's).

Comment: Better answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025472/118520