# Flask-SQLAlchemy validation: prevent adding to relationship based on other field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy and trying to validate input to my database. For single fields, the validate decorator works well. However, I'm having issues with preventing values from being added to a collection/relationship based the value of on another field. For example, consider the following data model:

```py
class MyRelation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "my_relation"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_data_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("my_data.id"))
    some_value = db.Column(db.String)

class MyData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "my_data"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    some_relation = db.relationship("MyRelation", backref="my_data")
    some_other_value = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

The problem I'm running into is I want to ensure `some_relation` is empty if `some_other_value == True`. I have looked into the following options. I'm not sure if any of these could be tuned to provide the intended functionality:

1. Use `@validates` with multiple fields as [specified here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025472/6814713). The problem with this approach is it seems to validate the collection one by one, and returning None in validation for poorly formed input yields `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Can't flush None value found in collection Job.alternate_attributes`. Returning an empty list also doesn't work.
2. Use a `before_insert` event listener, as [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147957/6814713). The challenge I see with this is this seems like this would not be compatible with relationship events per the [official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_events.html#mapper-level-events).
3. Use a `before_flush` event listener, which sounds like it might be compatible with this use case, but I'll be honest I'm having a hard time finding a good example of exactly how to use this given my goal. It's pretty abstract, and I don't see any examples in the docs ([both](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/examples.html#examples-versioned-history) of the [examples](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/examples.html#module-examples.versioned_rows) mentioned at the end of the [before_flush section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_events.html#before-flush) don't actually contain any reference to the `before_flush` method they're supposedly demonstrating).

Any guidance would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question - the `before_flush` event listener is the way to go here:

```py
@db.event.listens_for(db.session, 'before_flush')
def validate_and_modify_relationships(session, flush_context, instances):
    """
    Complex validation that cannot be performed with @valdiates
    """
    
    # new records only (for updates only, use session.dirty)
    for instance in session.new:
        if isinstance(instance, MyData):
            if instance.some_other_value:
                instance.some_relation = []
```

Works as expected, the only thing I wouldn't mind is if it could be an method on the `MyData` class with the rest of my `@validates` methods, but this is otherwise fairly clear.

Comment: see also: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_events.html#before-flush