# In SQLAlchemy, how should I specify that the relationship field is required?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model that depends on some fields on another model. This fields should be present when the record is created, but I do not see a way to enforce that on the database:

```
class Study(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    type = db.Column(Enum(StudyTypeChoices), nullable=False)
    owner_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('owner.id'), nullable=False)
    participants = db.relationship('Participant', lazy=True, cascade='save-update, merge, delete')
```

How can I make sure that 'participants' is provided when the Study record gets created (similar to what happens with the 'type' field)? I know I can put a wrapper around it to make sure of that, but I am wondering is there is a more neat way of doing it with sqlalchemy.

Edit: This is the definition of the Participant model

```
class Participant(UserBase):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey("user_base.id"), primary_key=True)
    study_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('study.id'))
```

Comment: Is there a foreign key relationship between study and particpants? (You might [edit] the question to include the relevant parts of the Participant model definition.)

Comment: @snakecharmerb: Indeed. But if I make it not nullable there, will this property be translated to Study? Edit: just tried it, and I can still create Study records without any participants.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68366099/2144390

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this implicitly, you would need to use `orm.validates` perhaps, or an event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to [`before_flush` events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_events.html#before-flush) and prevent flushes containing studies without participants by raising an exception for instance.

```py
@event.listens_for(Session, "before_flush")
def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    for instance in session.new:  # might want to inspect session.dirty as well
        if isinstance(instance, Study) and (
            instance.participants is None or instance.participants == []
        ):
            raise ValueError(
                f"Study {instance} cannot have {instance.participants} participants."
            )
```

This only checks for new studies, you might want to check in [`session.dirty`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.dirty) as well for updated studies.

Full demo:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base, relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class Study(Base):
    __tablename__ = "study"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    participants = relationship("Participant", uselist=True, back_populates="study")


class Participant(Base):
    __tablename__ = "participant"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    study_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("study.id"), nullable=True)
    study = relationship("Study", back_populates="participants")


@event.listens_for(Session, "before_flush")
def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    for instance in session.new:  # might want to inspect session.dirty as well
        if isinstance(instance, Study) and (
            instance.participants is None or instance.participants == []
        ):
            raise ValueError(
                f"Study {instance} cannot have {instance.participants} participants."
            )

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", future=True, echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

s1 = Study()
p1_1 = Participant()
p1_2 = Participant()
s1.participants.extend([p1_1, p1_2])

s2 = Study()

with Session(bind=engine) as session:
    session.add(s1)
    session.commit()  # OK

with Session(bind=engine) as session:
    session.add(s2)
    session.commit()  # ValueError
```