# How to set the value of a column in sqlalchemy based on two other columns of the same model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i am building a web application. i have the following model.

```
class Staff(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    username = db.Column(db.String(64))
    cell_phone = db.Column(db.Integer)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64))
    position = db.Column(db.String(64))
    # add average salary value based on payroll
```

i want the `username` to be `first_name+last_name` with the user typing **only** his first and last name in the form.

i know how to use `@db.event.listens_for(Staff, "after_insert")` etc and update it like that. But is there a way to define something within the model so it does it automatically without a triger?
`

Answer (score 7):

You should get familiar with `property` decorators.

For SQLAlchemy there is  [`hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) extension which I highly recommend to learn and use. Take a look at the example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Staff(db.Model):
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64))

    @hybrid_property
    def username(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name
```

Documentations shows exactly such an usage for hybrid properties: [SQL Expressions as Mapped Attributes: Using a Hybrid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-hybrid). Using a hybrid property you can easily use *username* to query your models and you do not need to store the data twice in your database. With a few additional lines you should be able to [create update constructs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property.update_expression) in the upcoming SQLAlchemy v1.2.

Edit: To state it explicitly - you can use `column_property` too (as stated in linked [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property)):

```
username = column_property(first_name + last_name)
```

Which may look better but is less powerful (has no update statement among others).

PS. I bet this is a duplicate but I cannot find an identical question.

Comment: if the username a `db.Column(db.String(64))` in your answer? can i also write it out as a column?

Comment: The `username` is not a column. It won't be stored in database (which is a good thing) but will *behave* like a column. For example having previously created `Staff(first_name='John', last_name='Smith')` you can query it with `Staff.query.filter_by(username='John Smith').one()`.

Comment: And the maximal difference of `username` is 128; you could use validators to restrain the sumaric length of two columns. Refer to this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580815/6646912

Comment: can i create a relationship to the username in another Model called Payroll for example? its a value i want to use in other models. it could be named full name for example instead of username.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But you can use still use composite foreign keys for this. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7504753/6646912 you can use foreign keys created in this manner to create a relationship. If you need help creating such a relation, this deserves a separate question.